# Iterate all inner NSDictionary items and change them?

Tags: nsstring, iteration, nsdictionary, mutable

In my particular case I have `NSDictionary` object which can contain `NSString` objects as keys and `NSString` and `NSDictionary` objects as values. The inner dictionaries can also contain `NSDictionary` objects.

What if I need to iterate all the inner `NSString` objects and append a letter to them? Note: I need to change both values and keys

Comment: Please at the very least specify whether you're working in Obj-C or Swift.

Comment: @Hamish Does `NSDictionary` behave differently if wrapped in Swift?

Comment: `NSDictionary` isn't mutable.

Comment: @Willeke No, but it'll be much more useful for answerers to know what language to answer in (otherwise the question is too vague IMO). And if it is Swift, OP should be using a Swift `Dictionary` and `String` anyway (although this whole data structure of dictionary with values that are either strings or dictionaries sounds a bit odd anyway – it's quite possible that OP should be using a model struct/class instead).

Comment: @Hamish, any language is applicable - I have both languages in my project. Suggest any solution with any language

Comment: Will downvoters finally write what they don't like in my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift:

```
func adjustNextLayer(inDictionary dictionary: inout [String:Any], for key: String) {
    if let newString = myDictionary[key] as? String {
        myDictionary[key] = "\(newString) insert some text to append here"
    } else {
        If let newDictionary = myDictionary[key] as? [String: Any] {
            newDictionary.keys.foreach { key in
                adjustNextLayer(inDictionary: newDictionary, for: key}
                myDictionary[key] = newDictionary
            }
        }
    }
}

let myDictionary = ["a":1, "b":2]
let keys = myDictionary.keys
keys.foreach { key in
    adjustNextLayer(inDictionary: myDictionary, for: key)
}
```

Remember that you can place functions inside of functions in swift. This would all be in one function of its own.

Of course, you could also use flatMap, but that goes at most two layers deep.

As for changing keys, why not set the previous key to nil and then make a new entry in the dictionary?

Comment: Could you please write the full answer?

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?